# Find a space before some numbers(time format) in regular expression

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a string and I want a regular expression to find whether there is a space before a number or not, if yes, then add one space before that.
For example: "TAXI CABS ONLY THURS-FRI-SAT 11:30PM-3:00AM"
and result: "TAXI CABS ONLY THURS-FRI-SAT 11:30 PM-3:00 AM"

Comment: `Before` a number or `after` a number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a regular expression expert, but ended up with these two variants:

1. First variant using a callback function as second parameter to `replace` method:

```js
var str = 'TAXI CABS ONLY THURS-FRI-SAT 11:30PM-3:00AM';
var strUpdated = str.replace(/\d?\d:\d?\d(AM|PM)/g, function(m){
  return m.replace(/(AM|PM)/g, " $1");
});
console.log('old: ' + str);
console.log('new: ' + strUpdated);
```

2. Second variant using expression as second parameter to `replace` method:

```js
var str = 'TAXI CABS ONLY THURS-FRI-SAT 11:30PM-3:00AM';
var strUpdated = str.replace(/(\d?\d:\d?\d)(AM|PM)/g, "$1 $2");
console.log('old: ' + str);
console.log('new: ' + strUpdated);
console.log('----------------------------------');
var str = 'Another test 1:22 AM. This 12:05PM and this 12:50PN ';
var strUpdated = str.replace(/(\d?\d:\d?\d)(AM|PM)/g, "$1 $2");
console.log('old: ' + str);
console.log('new: ' + strUpdated);
```

Now I will try to explain what the regex does :)

- `(\d?\d:\d?\d)` - this will match digits like 1:1, 11:22, 1:22, 11:2, the brakes are used to make a group so later could use it in the replace regex (second parameter of replace method)
- `(AM|PM)` - this is another group ( that we create when we put the brackets ) to match literal AM or PM

**EDIT** (*in response to [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46178819/find-a-space-before-some-numberstime-format-in-regular-expression/46179295?noredirect=1#comment79348014_46179295)*)

What I can propose quickly is to take care for cases like `11AM-6PM OR 8A-6P` in another regex and not complicate the current one. Have a look on the following code - the second `replace` is doing the job:

```js
var str = 'TAXI CABS ONLY THURS-FRI-SAT 11:30PM-3:00AM \r\n     11AM-6PM OR 8A-6P 11M-6M OR 12A-15P';
var strUpdated = str.replace(/(\d?\d:\d?\d)(AM|PM)/g, "$1 $2").replace(/(\d?\d)(AM|PM|A|P)/g, "$1 $2");
console.log('old: ' + str);
console.log('new: ' + strUpdated);
```

Comment: @ codtex, thanks for the explanation in details. what if, I have hours like this: 11AM-6PM OR 8A-6P. I need to extend this regular expression to cover all the possibilities.

Comment: @MaryamKoulaei you can have a look on the **EDIT** it should take care for those cases. As I said I'm not an regex expert and this was the quickest way that I came up with. If I need to extend the current regex I will need to spend some time

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check if a number is adjacent to a letter, and if so, add a space between those?

Check for all numbers `[0-9]` and then check if a letter is adjacent to it `[A-Zz-A]`. Then replace that nth character (defined by `$1`) with a space and keep the original character at that location by putting it at the `$2` location.

```
let str = 'TAXI CABS ONLY THURS-FRI-SAT 11:30PM-3:00AM';
str = str.replace(/([0-9])([A-Za-z])/ig, '$1 $2');
```